# How to reduce size DB2 Data Warehouse

Tags: db2-luw

in my environment I have two db2 for luw databases, which mostly contain LOB data. 1. main database which has 8TB 2. archive database 50TB which contains archive data transferred from 1 database. In the 2nd 50TB database, the data is not deleted, so the reorganization will not take effect. So what are the additional options for reducing the size of such a database. What should I start looking for free space from? are there any unused files or is it worth compressing the data in the database. I have db2 for LUW version 9.7 on AIX

Answer (score 0):

To reduce size of a database:

1. Only store data which is necessary

To archive this you need to

- Remove redundant data
- Compress data
- Remove data which is in archive and not used in main database
- Remove data which shouldn't be in the DWH because it's saved in an other place

But 8TB/50TB seems to be an enterprice level DWH so probable it would help to ask someone who can check this local.